# Filling in AcroFields with UTF-8 strings in iTextPdf

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, itext, acrofields

### I wish to fill in a PDF form with information containing special characters:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("in.pdf");
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("out.pdf"));

        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
        form.setField("sessionAddress", "ÕÄÖÜ õäöü šž");

        stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Using the above code, I see the following result in `out.pdf` (the part after `Aadress:`):

[image]

### Now, if I specify all of the special characters as unicode codes instead:

```java
form.setField("sessionAddress", "\u00D5\u00C4\u00D6\u00DC \u00F5\u00E4\u00F6\u00FC \u0161\u017E");
```

[image]

### What am I doing wrong?

As far as I know, strings represent a sequence of characters. Shouldn't the contents of the two above strings be equal in Java code?

I have a database full of UTF-8 encoded data. How can I make it work with iTextPdf directly like the rest of the Java application already does (the database, java code, API requests/responses and front-end JavaScript code all contain strings like this and everything works except iTextPdf).

If it is of any importance, the java file with the above code is saved in UTF-8. I am using IntelliJ to run the `main` method in a gradle project. iTextPdf version 5.5.13. Java 11.

Comment: I suspect that the encoding of your source file is not the same as when compiling. About your UTF-8 encoded data you'll have to convert it to a java string and it will work correctly in iText, this is a completely different situation of your source file.

Comment: @PauloSoares Thank you. You were right about the UTF-8 encoded data working straight out of the database. BUT, the whole project is built with the same compiler and gradle version. So how come all the UTF-8 strings in the project work with all the other libraries perfectly (database, Spring, email, etc)? How could I ever be sure that I am not just lucky, but everything works as expected? And most importantly: How to answer this question and make the UTF-8 encoded strings work with iTextPdf? What would I need to change in my build configuration?

Comment: `javac` with the `-encoding` option is what you are looking for.